# SQL error for operand

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used the same query to transfer from one database to another for ages, but suddenly I am getting the error

> "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Here is my SQL:

```
    INSERT INTO lightand_expressionengine.exp_channel_data (
    entry_id
    , site_id
    , channel_id
    , field_id_1
    , field_ft_1
    , field_id_3
    , field_ft_3
    , field_id_7
    , field_ft_7
    , field_id_8
    , field_ft_8
    , field_id_9
    , field_ft_9
    , field_id_11
    , field_ft_11
    , field_id_12
    , field_ft_12
    , field_id_13
    , field_ft_13
    , field_id_14
    , field_ft_14
    , field_id_16
    , field_ft_16
    , field_id_17
    , field_ft_17
    )
SELECT (
        entry_id
        , site_id
        , channel_id
        , field_id_1
        , field_ft_1
        , field_id_3
        , field_ft_3
        , field_id_7
        , field_ft_7
        , field_id_8
        , field_ft_8
        , field_id_9
        , field_ft_9
        , field_id_11
        , field_ft_11
        , field_id_12
        , field_ft_12
        , field_id_13
        , field_ft_13
        , field_id_14
        , field_ft_14
        , field_id_16
        , field_ft_16
        , field_id_17
        , field_ft_17
        )
FROM lightand_expressionengineold.exp_channel_data
```

Can anyone see what the issue is? I cant figure it out.

Comment: Just removing the parenthesis from the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the opening and closing brackets i.e. `(...)` from the `SELECT`. I.e. try the following SQL.

```
INSERT INTO lightand_expressionengine.exp_channel_data (
entry_id
, site_id
, channel_id
, field_id_1
, field_ft_1
, field_id_3
, field_ft_3
, field_id_7
, field_ft_7
, field_id_8
, field_ft_8
, field_id_9
, field_ft_9
, field_id_11
, field_ft_11
, field_id_12
, field_ft_12
, field_id_13
, field_ft_13
, field_id_14
, field_ft_14
, field_id_16
, field_ft_16
, field_id_17
, field_ft_17
)
SELECT
    entry_id
    , site_id
    , channel_id
    , field_id_1
    , field_ft_1
    , field_id_3
    , field_ft_3
    , field_id_7
    , field_ft_7
    , field_id_8
    , field_ft_8
    , field_id_9
    , field_ft_9
    , field_id_11
    , field_ft_11
    , field_id_12
    , field_ft_12
    , field_id_13
    , field_ft_13
    , field_id_14
    , field_ft_14
    , field_id_16
    , field_ft_16
    , field_id_17
    , field_ft_17
FROM lightand_expressionengineold.exp_channel_data
```